# How to get all combination of (numbers from a list) and (simple math operators)

Tags: for-loop, combinatorics

Ok, so if you have a list of numbers (any size) like this:

```
[5, 7] (It's short so i can type all the combinations)
```

I want like a loop that returns a list of combinations like this:

```
5+7
5-7
5*7
5/7
7+5
7-5
7*5
7/5
```

I have thought about this for a while and I know it's structured in a tree diagram but i just don't know how to make it work for any size of list.

Comment: Define what "all combinations" actually means for more than two elements. If, say, we have ``[1, 2, 3]`` what are the desired outputs? E.g. ``1+2+3``, ``(1+2)+3`` and ``1+(2+3)`` are all equivalent but written in a different way. Do these count as 1? And if so, which of them do you want to be produced?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use recursive algorithm like:

```
combination(list)
  for(numbers,operators)
     combination_list+=number+operation+combination(rest)
  return combination_list
```

you can do it by using iterative approach as well as any recursive algorithm has an iterative counterpart

Answer (score 0):

A general solution

```
void operations(int[] numbers){
    int size =  //determine the number of elements in the array
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < size;j++){
                if( i !=j){
                /*do all the operations 
                      numbers[i] + numbers[j] 
                      numbers[i] - numbers[j] 
                      numbers[i] * numbers[j] 
                      numbers[i] / numbers[j] 
            */
                }
            }
        }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little about the combinatorics behind this first:
Generating all possible orderings of the integer list will be N! combinations, and onto each of those combinations then all of the possible selections of operators between them, [number of operators]^[number of gaps between integers], so 4^(n-1)
multiplying those two numbers together for the total number of listings you will have: N!*(4^(n-1))

Just adding a third integer to the list will get you 96 possible combinations, and a fourth for 1536, I'm sure you knew though this will grow really quickly.

(and I'm also ignoring the fact that if your list has duplicate integers you don't need to create duplicate permutations of that list, so all of the above only applies to a list of unique integers)

I think the way I would try this would be to first create a listing of all permutations of the N many integers and a listing of all of the N-1 many selections of operators separately. Then combining them into one much larger listing using a pair of foreach loops.

```
List<Integer[]> orderings = //a bunch of arrays each one being a unique ordering of all integers in the inital listing
List<Character[]> selections = //a bunch of arrays each one being a unique selection of the 4 operators
List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Integer[] order : orderings) {
    for(Character[] selection : selections) {
        //now combine order (numbers) and selection(operators) alternating between indexes
        String combination = order[0].toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            combination += selection[i].toString() + order[i+1].toString();
        }
        combinations.add(combination);
    }
}
```

generating the permutations of the numbers is like finding all the possible orderings for a deck of cards, it's a problem that should have many easily find-able solutions elsewhere on stack overflow, and finding all the selections of operators isn't much harder either.

Edit: Oh, I just realized that I'm not sure if you were specifically wanted only pairs of numbers, so a list of 3 numbers will only output pairings of any two integers, not orderings containing all 3, if it's just pairs of numbers then the problem gets a bit simpler.